# Is this solution for the fourier transform correct? Thank you!

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

If not, could you please show me how to do it? I would really appreciate it!

**Quesiton**

> Consider the function
> $$
> f(t)=\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda|t|} \cos (\sigma t)
> $$
> with positive parameters $\lambda$ and $\sigma$, Calculate the Fourier transformation $\tilde{f}(\omega)$.

**Solution**

Use the definition of the Fourier transform:
$$\tilde{f}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-i\omega t} dt$$

Substitute the function f(t) into the equation:
$$\tilde{f}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (e^{\lambda |t|})cos(\sigma t) e^{-i\omega t} dt$$

Split the integral into two parts, one for t >= 0 and one for t < 0:
$$\tilde{f}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\lambda t}cos(\sigma t) e^{-i\omega t} dt + \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-\lambda t}cos(\sigma t) e^{-i\omega t} dt\right)$$

Use the substitution u = $e^{\lambda t}$ in the first integral:
$$\tilde{f}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\lambda}\left(\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{cos(\sigma \ln u)}{u} e^{-i\omega \ln u} du + \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{-\lambda t}cos(\sigma t) e^{-i\omega t} dt\right)$$

Use the substitution $v = \sigma t$ in the second integral:
$$\tilde{f}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\lambda}\left(\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{cos(\sigma \ln u)}{u} e^{-i\omega \ln u} du + \frac{1}{\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{0} cos(v) e^{-i(\omega/\sigma) v} dv\right)$$

Use the definition of the cosine transform and the definition of the inverse cosine transform:
$$\tilde{f}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\lambda}\left(\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{cos(\sigma \ln u)}{u} e^{-i\omega \ln u} du + \frac{1}{\sigma} \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}(\delta(\omega + \sigma) + \delta(\omega - \sigma))\right)$$

Simplify the first integral by completing the square in the exponent and applying a change of variables:

$$\tilde{f}(\omega)=\left(\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda^2 + (\omega + \sigma)^2}} + \frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda^2 + (\omega - \sigma)^2}}\right) + \frac{1}{\sigma} \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}(\delta(\omega + \sigma) + \delta(\omega - \sigma))$$

Simplify the expression by combining the two terms:
$$\tilde{f}(\omega)=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2 + (\omega + \sigma)^2} + \frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2 + (\omega - \sigma)^2}$$

**NEW SOLUTION**

Lets calculate the Fourier transform of the function, $\mathrm{g}(\sigma, \mathrm{t})=\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda|t|} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \sigma \mathrm{t}}$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{G}(\sigma, \omega)=\mathcal{F}\{\mathrm{g}(\sigma, \mathrm{t})\} & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \omega \mathrm{t}} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \sigma t-\lambda|t|} \mathrm{dt} \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \omega \mathrm{t}} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \sigma t-\lambda \mathrm{t}} \mathrm{dt}+\int_{-\infty}^0 \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \omega t} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \sigma t+\lambda t} \mathrm{dt} \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \omega t+\mathrm{i} \sigma t-\lambda \mathrm{t}} \mathrm{dt}-\int_0^{-\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \omega t+\mathrm{i} \sigma t+\lambda t} \mathrm{dt} \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \omega t+\mathrm{i} \sigma t-\lambda \mathrm{t}} \mathrm{dt}+\int_0^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \omega t-\mathrm{i} \sigma t-\lambda \mathrm{t}} \mathrm{dt} \\
& =\frac{\left[\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \omega t+\mathrm{i} \sigma t-\lambda t}\right]_0^{\infty}}{-\mathrm{i} \omega+\mathrm{i} \sigma-\lambda}+\frac{\left[\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \omega \mathrm{t}-\mathrm{i} \sigma t-\lambda t}\right]_0^{\infty}}{\mathrm{i} \omega-\mathrm{i} \sigma-\lambda} \\
& =\frac{0-1}{-\mathrm{i} \omega+\mathrm{i} \sigma-\lambda}+\frac{0-1}{\mathrm{i} \omega-\mathrm{i} \sigma-\lambda} \\
& =\frac{1}{\lambda+\mathrm{i}(\omega-\sigma)}+\frac{1}{\lambda-\mathrm{i}(\omega-\sigma)} \\
& =\frac{\mathrm{i}(\omega+\sigma)+\lambda-\mathrm{i}(\omega-\sigma)+\lambda}{\lambda^2+(\omega+\sigma)^2} \\
& =\frac{2 \lambda}{\lambda^2+(\omega-\sigma)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Here in the 4th line of integration $t$ is replaced by $-\mathrm{t}$. and although $\mathrm{e}^{\pm \mathrm{i}(\omega-\sigma) \mathrm{t}} \sin$ is not defined at $\mathrm{t}>$ $\infty$ but for exponential decay part $\lim _{\mathrm{t} \rightarrow \infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda \mathrm{t}} \mathrm{e}^{\pm \mathrm{i}(\omega-\sigma) \mathrm{t}}=0$.

Similarly for, $\mathrm{g}(-\sigma, \mathrm{t})=\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda|t|} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \sigma \mathrm{t}}$ the fourier transformation will be,
$$
\mathrm{G}(-\sigma, \omega)=\mathcal{F}\{\mathrm{g}(-\sigma, \mathrm{t})\}=\frac{2 \lambda}{\lambda^2+(\omega+\sigma)^2}
$$

$\mathrm{f}(\mathrm{t})=\mathrm{e}^{-\lambda|t|} \cos (\sigma \mathrm{t})$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{F}(\omega)=\mathcal{F}\{\mathrm{f}(\mathrm{t})\} & =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \omega \mathrm{t}} \mathrm{e}^{-\lambda|\mathrm{t}|} \cos (\sigma \mathrm{t}) \mathrm{dt} \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \omega t} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} \sigma t-\lambda|t|} \mathrm{dt}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \omega t} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} \sigma t-\lambda|t|} \mathrm{dt}\right] \\
& =\frac{1}{2}[\mathrm{G}(\sigma, \omega)+\mathrm{G}(-\sigma, \omega)] \\
& =\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{2 \lambda}{\lambda^2+(\omega-\sigma)^2}+\frac{2 \lambda}{\lambda^2+(\omega+\sigma)^2}\right] \\
& =\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2+(\omega+\sigma)^2}+\frac{\lambda}{\lambda^2+(\omega-\sigma)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Check the signs on $e^{\lambda t}$.

Comment: This has a couple of issues. The question has the correct function $e^{-\lambda|t|}$ but then all of your work uses the wrong function $e^{\lambda|t|}$. Next, both of your substitutions on both parts don't make sense. You undo the first change of variables anyway when you say you "complete the square and apply a change of variables" and in the second one the factor of $e^{-\lambda t}$ vanishes without any explanation. Combining like terms would not make the deltas disappear at the end. I would start over and use the fact that the function to be transformed is even to simplify the integrand.

Comment: @NinadMunshi thank you for pointing all of those mistakes out! except for the the part where I used the wrong exponential function with a the wrong sign, I seem to be getting stuck at each step. If you have the time, I would greatly appreciate if you could show me how to do what you just said

Comment: $e^{-i\omega t} = \cos \omega t - i \sin \omega t$ which splits your integral into two. What can you say about the party of each integral?

Comment: The two parts of the integral correspond to the real and imaginary parts of the Fourier transform, respectively. The first integral represents the real part and the second integral represents the imaginary part.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo. I meant parity not party.

Comment: The parity of each integral depends on the parity of the original function. If the original function is even, then its Fourier transform will also be even. If the original function is odd, then its Fourier transform will be odd. The parity of a function determines whether it is symmetric or antisymmetric with respect to the origin. An even function is symmetric around the origin, while an odd function is antisymmetric around the origin.

Comment: oh right, sorry, i understood your question wrong

Comment: Mathematica tells this is the right solution: $\tilde{f}(\omega)=\frac{\frac{\lambda }{\lambda ^2+(\omega -\sigma )^2}+\frac{\lambda }{\lambda ^2+(\sigma +\omega )^2}}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}$

Comment: @gpmath hmm, so it is close to what I got, would you perhaps know the correct steps of how to do it?

Comment: Check this: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=fourier+exp%28-lambda*abs%28t%29%29*cos%28sigma*t%29%2C+t%2C+omega)

Comment: @NinadMunshi I have taken your advise and edited the solution, how does it look now?

Comment: @gpmath thank you!